# 1000hz bootstrap-validator resetForm Validation results

Tags: validation, jquery-ui, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using this v-0.9.0 version of Validator.js,

I used below code,

```
$('#frmNew')[0].reset()
$('#frmNew').validator('destroy').validator()
```

When i use resetForm, Validation symbols and colors[Red & Green] are still exist in screen. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue in `1000hz bootstrap-validator` with no proper fix yet, can check this issue [Destroy method doesnt remove icons](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/123)  on github

Possible solution is add following piece of code when `reset` or `destroy` the form and remove `error` and `success` classes.

```
this.$element.find('.has-error').removeClass('has-error')

var $feedback = this.$element.find('.form-control-feedback')
$feedback.removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-remove')

this.$element.find('.has-success').removeClass('has-success')

var $feedback = this.$element.find('.form-control-feedback')
$feedback.removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-ok')
```

**Suggestion**

Use [this](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) BootstrapValidator validation plugin, it gives more control to validate form fields, designed to use with Bootstrap 3 and will not face these types of issues & bugs.

Comment: Thanks @shehary. It helps me.